# Changing output markup of an media file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress theme for a friend and am trying to add some markup before and after an image that has been inserted using the media button on a post.

Here is what I have so far but it's giving me an error. Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated!

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'wpse264886_content_insert_html', 10, 1);
function wpse264886_content_insert_html ($content) {
  $html1 = 'before ... ';
  $html2    =  'after ...';
  $content = preg_replace('/(<a.*?)><(img.*?)/', '$1>' . $html1 . '<$2>' . $html2, $content);
  return $content;
  }
```

Thanks!

Ponte

Comment: Welcome to SO. To improve your chances of getting an answer, I suggest you a) post the error message and b) tag your question with a language (PHP?)

Comment: Hi Johnny! Thanks so much for the welcome and the suggestions. I will get to that now =)

Comment: Looking at the page I just get the http//imagelocation that spits out on the page. Not so much an error

Comment: I don't do much PHP and no Wordpress, so I can't help. That's why tagging the question is important. It attracts people who can answer.